# Skip a child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't want css to be applied to a child element.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="subchild">
            <p> subchild </p>
        </div>
        <p> child </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply css to all `div`s except the `subchild` `div` and its children.

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: In this particular case you might just write `#main, #child {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, simply apply the CSS to all `div`s and then reverse it for the `subchild`:

```
#child
{
    display: inline;
    background-color: black;
}
#child #subchild
{
    /* Assuming this was blocked/transparent before the '.child' css applied. */
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```